# Можно ли вставить изображение под спойлер в readme.md?

Tags: git, github

Можно ли вставить изображение под спойлер в readme.md?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вот так можно:

```
<details>
 
[![введите сюда описание изображения][1]][1]
 
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKtls.jpg
 
</details>
```

Получится следующее:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и при раскрытии:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Если хотите добавить свой заголовок, то:

```
<details>
<summary>Заголовок спойлера</summary>
 
[![введите сюда описание изображения][1]][1]
 
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKtls.jpg
 
</details>
```